# Trouble with boost::spirit::lex - punctuation characters

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-lex

I want to create a lex::token_def<> that contains character sequences like '[' or ']' or '&>'

I tried escaping the necessary characters:

```
namespace lex = boost::spirit::lex;

enum LexerIDs { ID_IDENTIFIER, ID_WHITESPACE, ID_INTEGER, ID_FLOAT, ID_PUNCTUATOR };

template <typename Lexer>
struct my_lexer : lex::lexer<Lexer>
{
    my_lexer() : punctuator("\[|\]|\(|\)|\.|&>|\*\*|\*|\+|-|~|!|/|%|<<|>>|<|>|<=|>=|==|!=")
    {
        this->self.add(punctuator, ID_PUNCTUATOR);
    }
    lex::token_def<> punctuator;
};
```

but this gives me some warning about unrecognized escaped characters & lexing a string with it fails. How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra escaping level:

```
my_lexer() : punctuator("\\[|\\]|\\(|\\)|\\.|&>|\\*\\*|\\*|\\+|-|~|!|/|%|<<|>>|<|>|<=|>=|==|!=")
```

`"\\"` is a string literal containing one backslash, which the lexer constructor then parses.

Comment: thank you - that's it. The only unfortunate thing is that the regular expressions get an additional layer of 'obfuscation'

Comment: @TobiasLangner If you can use c++11, [raw string literals](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#raw-strings) can help a lot.